# how to specify parameter of "prices" of telegram API method of "sendInvoice" in the URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot, urlfetch

My scripting language is Google-script. Can anyone show how to specify the last parameter in the URL which is 'prices'.

```
var url = telegramUrl + "/sendInvoice?chat_id=" + id + "&title='asdf'&description='fasdafa'&payload='sfad'&provider_token='398062629:T EST:999999999_F91D8F69C042267444B74CC0B3C747757EB0E065'&currency='UZS'&prices  =[]";
```

Comment: Can you link the official api doc with the method you're referring to?

Comment: Sure. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendinvoice

Comment: Should be something like `prices=[{label:"Service",amount:500},{label:"Tax",amount:100}]`

Comment: Thank you. It seem there is still something wrong with the URL. When I try to run the "sendInvoice" function, it says: invalid argument: 
 
 
 
 https://api.telegram.org/bot912814279:AAEl4FHjAcPZtFtyPFfK1g7ZgnOmfFP6x2A/sendInvoice?chat_id=undefined&title='asdf'&description='fasdafa'&payload='sfad'&provider_token='398063629:TEST:999999999_F91D8F89C042267544B74CC0B3C747757EB0E065'&start_parameter='1'&currency='UZS'&prices=[{label:'Service',amount:500},{label:'Tax',amount:100}] (строка 31, файл Код)

Comment: There seems to be a space after ``price=[``. Also  you need to encode your query string:`encodeURI( your query string)` See [`urlfetch` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params). Try sending  sendingit as written in the example. You can also try `prices={label:"Service",amount:500}&prices={label:"Tax",amount:100}`. Encodeuri in all cases. If that doesn't work, send it as json instead.

Answer (score 0):

Acording Telegram API
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#labeledprice

This is the correct way working on Telegram Payments 2.0

**&prices=[{"label":"MyService","amount":692},{"label":"TAX","amount":120}]**

Full code:

```
$response = file_get_contents($path.'/sendinvoice?chat_id='.$chatId.'&title=The Service Title&description=Your Service Description&payload=12&provider_token=28434533:TEST:YTVjMDfghNGI1&currency=EUR&prices=[{"label":"MyService","amount":692},{"label":"TAX","amount":120}]');
```